# Hive: Using select inside select

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

First I used the query:

```
select name
from tab1
where id in (select id
             from (select id,count(id) as a 
                   from tab2
                   group by id
                   order by a desc limit 1) ;
```

and I came to know that select inside select is not possible in hive.
So I modified it using variable.

```
set var1= select count(id) as a from tab2 group by id order by a desc limit 1;

select name from tab1 group by name having count(id)='${hiveconf:var1}';
```

But in the place of `'${hiveconf:var1}'`, the query got substitued and again getting the same error.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What was the error you got when you ran the 1st query? each sub query in hive has to have an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  t1.name 

from            tab1 t1 

        join   (select      id
                           ,count(*) as cnt
                from        tab2 
                group by    id 
                order by    cnt desc 
                limit       1
                ) t2 

        on      t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Got the following error.                                                                          Error [10128] :Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'

Comment: There's no point in an order by in the inner select.  Just remove it completely.

Comment: @Andrew - It comes with `limit`

Comment: Ah, missed that. Your change to use the alias should work then.